# Type Alias Declaration with templates in Swift

Tags: swift, templates, generics

How to avoid redundant declaration of restriction in functions `f0`, `f1`, ... `f10`?

```
class SomeClass<T: UnsignedInteger> {

    func f0<S: Sequence>(sequence: S) where S.Iterator.Element == T { }    
    func f1<S: Sequence>(sequence: S) where S.Iterator.Element == T { }
    ......
    func f10<S: Sequence>(sequence: S) where S.Iterator.Element == T { }
}
```

How to declare something like this:

```
typealias S = Sequence where S.Iterator.Element == T

func f0(sequence: S) { }
func f1(sequence: S) { }
......
func f10(sequence: S) { }
```

?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can do exactly what you are asking. A typealias is a symbol that can be used in place of an existing type, it is not a restriction pattern.

You could fix the function types to that of the class declaration by adding an additional generic placehoder type (S) to the class defintion:

```
class SomeClass0<T: UnsignedInteger, S: Sequence> where S.Iterator.Element == T {

    func f0(sequence: S) { }
    func f1(sequence: S) { }
}
```

But that means that referencing the type is pretty ugly, unless you can infer types from an init etc..

```
let instance0 = SomeClass0<UInt, [UInt]>()
```

You could still fix the sequence type at the class level with the placeholder type, but leave out the UnsignedInteger placeholder, depending on exactly how you are using it:

```
class SomeClass1<S: Sequence> where S.Iterator.Element: UnsignedInteger {

    typealias T = S.Iterator.Element

    func f0(sequence: S) { }
    func f1(sequence: S) { }

    func f99(number: T) {}
}

let instance1 = SomeClass1<[UInt]>()
```