# How can I avoid repeating these type constraints?

Tags: swift

A have a lot of functions with the following signature:

```
func defilter_up<ReferenceLine:Collection>(line:ReferenceLine) where ReferenceLine.Iterator.Element == UInt8, ReferenceLine.Index == Int

func defilter_average<ReferenceLine:Collection>(line:ReferenceLine) where ReferenceLine.Iterator.Element == UInt8, ReferenceLine.Index == Int

func defilter_sub<ReferenceLine:Collection>(line:ReferenceLine) where ReferenceLine.Iterator.Element == UInt8, ReferenceLine.Index == Int
```

etc.

These type constraints are getting very long and unwieldy. Is there a good way I can avoid repeating typing them out, something equivalent to a `typealias` for generics?

Comment: A similar question was recently asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895949/type-alias-declaration-with-templates-in-swift.

Comment: @MartinR undeleting this because the other question seems to be about constraining generics with other generic type parameters

Comment: Yes, it is a similar question, not the same.

Comment: Either make the parent scope generic, and add the constraints there, or wait for the the release of this feature, which will implement where clauses on associated types https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0142-associated-types-constraints.md

Comment: @Alexander would that involve declaring a protocol

Comment: @taylorswift So declare a protocol :p

Answer (score 1):

You can make the containing class/struct generic:

```
struct MyClass<ReferenceLine:Collection where 
    ReferenceLine.Iterator.Element == UInt8, 
    ReferenceLine.Index == Int> {

    func defilterUp(line: ReferenceLine) { ... }
    func defilterAverage(line: ReferenceLine) { ... }
    func defilterSub(line: ReferenceLine) { ... }
}
```

Another option is to refactor the code such that they are functions *of* the genericized object, like below. This is a substantial change in the structure of your code, so without context I can't say for sure this will work for your use case.

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == UInt8, Index == Int {
    func defilterUp() { ... }
    func defilterAverage() { ... }
    func defilterSub() { ... }
}
```

If these functions are meant to be private to a single class, you can mimic the access control by making this a `private extension` and put it in the same file as the using class.